# Lucene - Which field contains search term?

Tags: lucene

I have developed a search application with Lucene. I have created the basic search. Basically, my app works as follows:

- My index has many fields. (Around 40)
- User can enter query to multiple fields i.e: **+NAME:John +SURNAME:Doe**
- Queries can contain wildcards such as ? and * i.e: **+NAME:J?hn +SURNAME:Do***
- Queries can also contain fuzzy i.e: **+NAME:Jahn~0.5**

Now, I want to find, which field(s) contains my search term(s). As I am using wildcard and fuzzy, I cannot just make string comparison. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for debugging purposes, you could use [IndexSearcher.explain](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29).

Otherwise, this problem looks like highlighting, so you should be able to find out the fields that matched by:

- re-analyzing your document,
- or using its term vectors.